# Convert PowerShell array to integer

Tags: powershell

I've the following result from a PowerShell array:

```
Level
-----
    0
```

How can I convert it to an Int to retrieve only the value which is the number under the level?

Comment: `$myArray.Level` should do. What you're seeing is an object with a property (probably).

Comment: Alternatively use `$myArray | Select-Object -Expand Level`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Ansgar said, use Select-Object with the -ExpandProperty parameter. I like that best as if .value isnt there for some reason it wont error out.

If it MUST be a INT then you can cast it like this:

```
[int]($MyArray | select -ExpandProperty Level)
```